# The class 'WebViewController' doesn't have an unnamed constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, webview-flutter

I have a problem with my flutter app using the package [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)  , here Is my code:

**pubspec.yaml**

```yaml
  webview_flutter: ^4.0.6
```

**dart**

```
  WebViewController breachWebViewController = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          // Update loading bar.
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) {},
        onPageFinished: (String url) {},
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
    )
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'));
```

but I am getting this error :

```
The class 'WebViewController' doesn't have an unnamed constructor.
Try using one of the named constructors defined in 'WebViewController'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I just got this problem as a result of someone else having upgraded `webview_flutter` to a newer version.
(The constructor changed in [the major version change from 3 to 4 for this module](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/versions/4.0.0#migrating-from-30-to-40)).

To update this dependency to the correct version in my environment I needed to do:

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

(And in my case it was a sub module, not the main app - I needed to go into the module that used `webview_flutter` and run that command there)

---

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that I was using an older version of the package.

I needed to manually enter the correct version in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the library example project you have to initialize the controller in this way, taken from here https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example:

```
late final WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // #docregion platform_features
    late final PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams params;
    if (WebViewPlatform.instance is WebKitWebViewPlatform) {
      params = WebKitWebViewControllerCreationParams(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
        mediaTypesRequiringUserAction: const <PlaybackMediaTypes>{},
      );
    } else {
      params = const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();
    }

    final WebViewController controller =
        WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(params);
    // #enddocregion platform_features

    controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            debugPrint('WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)');
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            debugPrint('Page started loading: $url');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            debugPrint('Page finished loading: $url');
          },
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
            debugPrint('''
Page resource error:
  code: ${error.errorCode}
  description: ${error.description}
  errorType: ${error.errorType}
  isForMainFrame: ${error.isForMainFrame}
          ''');
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              debugPrint('blocking navigation to ${request.url}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            debugPrint('allowing navigation to ${request.url}');
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..addJavaScriptChannel(
        'Toaster',
        onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
          );
        },
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'));

    // #docregion platform_features
    if (controller.platform is AndroidWebViewController) {
      AndroidWebViewController.enableDebugging(true);
      (controller.platform as AndroidWebViewController)
          .setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    }
    // #enddocregion platform_features

    _controller = controller;
  }
```